# rewrite rule to remove file extention and action

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule to remove file extention and action from it.

For example this url:

```
password.php?action=new
```

should be rewritten as:

```
password/new
```

I am trying following:

```
RewriteRule ^password/([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ /password.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It does not seem to work.

Also instead of specifying password.php file, how can i generalize it for every file? For example

```
file1.php?action=edit
file1/edit

file2.php?action=something
file2/something
```

Comment: no problem, can you edit and include your entire `.htaccess` file, or the relevant parts in anycase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this generic rule:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?action=$2 [L,QSA]
```

- `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f` checks for presence of corresponding `.php` file in site root directory before adding `.php` in front of it.
- `Options -MultiViews` disables [content negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html) features.

Comment: I get 500 Internal Server Error with it.

Comment: This rule is working fine on my Apache. For 500 you will need to check Apache error.log and paste relevant log message here. Also make sure this is in site root .htaccess and not in a subdirectory.